# Can't upload photo from Storage Access Framework on Android 4.4 using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer, android-4.4-kitkat

I have this code for uploading photo on server

```
photo: function () {
        var self = this;
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function
            getPhotoTicket(function (ticket) {
                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                var fileName = {};
                options.fileKey = "upload_file";      
                try {
                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, onSuccess, onError);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e.toString());
                    fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)+'.jpg';
                }
                options.fileName = fileName;
                options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                options.chunkedMode = false;
                options.headers = {
                    Connection: "keep-alive"
                };
                options.httpMethod = "POST";
                var params = {};
                params.upload_ticket = ticket;

                options.params = params;
                function reload() {
                    getProfile(userID, function () {
                        app.profile_editor();
                    }, true);
                }

                function onSuccess(fileEntry) {
                    fileName = fileEntry.name;
                }

                function onError(fileEntry) {
                    fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '.jpg';
                }

                var ft = new FileTransfer();           
                ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(URL + "api/index/fileupload"), function (success) {
                    alert('PHOTO UPDATED');
                    reload();
                }, function (error) {
                    alert('error');
                }, options);
            });
        }, function () {
            console.log("error getting image")
        }, {
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    }
```

it works fine on Android 4.3 and lower. But on Android KitKat i get imageURI like:

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A352

In this post  [Unable to load image when selected from the gallery on Android 4.4 (KitKat) using PhoneGap Camera Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638932/unable-to-load-image-when-selected-from-the-gallery-on-android-4-4-kitkat-usin)
MBillau suggest to set the destination type to DATA_URL. I tried but had no success. Could someone suggest how I need to  refactor my code?