# Unable to set image source when accessing image from gallery-Android

Tags: android, image, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Iam using cordova 3.4. When i capture an image and set it,its working fine but when I try to access on image from gallery I get the url

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%4A463
```

and I get image load error in my image tag.I know this is a know bug going around and I have refered stack questions such as [Unable to load image when selected from the gallery on Android 4.4 (KitKat) using PhoneGap Camera Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638932/unable-to-load-image-when-selected-from-the-gallery-on-android-4-4-kitkat-usin)

I cannot use the rough work around mentioned where URI is set manually like content://media/external/images/media/ because we focus devices with internal built in storage such as Moto

Also can you please confirm that this issue has been fixed in cordova 3.5.Because I require permission from my officials for download and I must make sure it is achievable .Can somebody please help

UPDATE:

```
app.directive('upload', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        elm.on('click', function() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                    function(imageURI) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            alert(imageURI);
                               ctrl.$setViewValue(imageURI);
                        });
                        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(fileEntry)                                                                       {
                             //                                                   ctrl.$setViewValue(imageURI);
                            alert("inside local file" + imageURI);
                            alert("Inside local file system");
                            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
                                alert("hai");
                                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                                options.fileKey = "file";
                                options.fileName = fileObj.name;
                                options.mimeType = fileObj.type;
                                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                                // var url = fileUploadUrl;
                                // ft.upload(imageUri, encodeURI(url), success,                 failure, options);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('error', false);
                    }, {quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
            );
        });
    }
};
       });
```

My HTML:

```
  <img
                    ng-src="{{onepic}}" 
                    width="250" 
                    height="390" 
                    alt="error"/>
```

I set value for onepic in my controller inside watch function.So when directive returns a URI it will be automatically set in onepic.Please specify any alternative solution or if Iam doing anything wrong ,Iam new to angularjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

In Camera Plugin there is one `FileHelper.java` File, Replace  the plugin `getRealPath` with my this my method.

For more details you can follow this ->  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5398

FileHelper.java

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static String getRealPath(String uriString, CordovaInterface cordova) {
        String realPath = null;


        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat) {
        Cursor cursor =  cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(uriString), null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":")+1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query( 
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        realPath = path;
        cursor.close();
        }else{

        if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
            String[] proj = { _DATA };
            Cursor cursor = cordova.getActivity().managedQuery(Uri.parse(uriString), proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            realPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            if (realPath == null) {
                LOG.e(LOG_TAG, "Could get real path for URI string %s", uriString);
            }
        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
            realPath = uriString.substring(7);
            if (realPath.startsWith("/android_asset/")) {
                LOG.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot get real path for URI string %s because it is a file:///android_asset/ URI.", uriString);
                realPath = null;
            }
        } else {
            realPath = uriString;
        }

        }
        return realPath;
    }
```

In `CameraLauncher.java` Class therer is one method `processResultFromGallery`

```
private void processResultFromGallery
```

Find this code:

```
    if (this.targetHeight == -1 && this.targetWidth == -1 &&
                (destType == FILE_URI || destType == NATIVE_URI) && !this.correctOrientation){

        this.callbackContext.success(uri.toString());
    }
```

And replace with this:

```
    if (this.targetHeight == -1 && this.targetWidth == -1 &&
                (destType == FILE_URI || destType == NATIVE_URI) && !this.correctOrientation) {

            String s    =FileHelper.getRealPath(uri.toString(), cordova);
            Log.i("test","<<<<ifURI::::::"+s +"URI::::" + uri.toString());
            this.callbackContext.success(s);

     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate.But its still not able to set image in my app page

Comment: Iam using angularjs directive to use plugin.When i comment out sourcetype Iam able to capture image and set it in my image tag.But if I specify source type for gallery,I can access gallery but while setting image I get the image not loaded symbol and alt text is displayed

Comment: Hey mate.Your code worked well but now when I tried to take picture using my app...the app stops working and exits app.Can you say whats wrong

Comment: When I access the gallery I can get and set image just fine.But when I take picture using camera,I can access camera and take picture but after that when the path is returned to img src to set image the app stops..Iam using kitkat..This feature works with original plugin code..Thank you so much for helping me through this

Comment: Just used two different function calls to Filehelper.java from cameraLauncher.java....Used your function for gallery access and cordova's original function for camera..This fixed my issue

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still see the error:

GET content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A4710 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638932/unable-to-load-image-when-selected-from-the-gallery-on-android-4-4-kitkat-usin) answer:

```
    if (imageUri.toString().substring(0,21).equals("content://com.android")) {
          String [] photo_split= imageUri.toString().split("%3A");
          String imageUriBasePath = "content://media/external/images/media/"+photo_split[1];
           imageUri= Uri.parse(imageUriBasePath );

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever some `uri` is passed into `<img src="uri" />` it's implicitly decoded from

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A9888 **(1)**

into

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:9888 **(2)**

However, after returning from `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` Android provides you with the read permission for  **(1)**, not **(2)**. In this case `WebView` will expectantly log an error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri
>   content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:9888
>   from pid=13163, uid=10165 requires
>   android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

or

> Unable to open content URL

**Code snippet**

All you need to resolve the issue is

```
    String uriToUseInWebView = transformForWebView(uri.toString());

    private String transformForWebView(String uri) {
        for (int i = 0; i < timesDecodingWebView(); i++)
            uri = uri.replace("%", Uri.encode("%"));
        return uri;
    }

    private int timesDecodingWebView() {
        if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equals("4.4.2")) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

in your Java code before passing `uri` into HTML/JS to ensure that **(1)** will be actually loaded.

I've tested that on 4.4.2, 4.4.4 and 5.0. The funny part is that Android 4.4.2 decodes the `uri` internally twice.