# cordova load image from cdvfile:// error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: angularjs, cordova, meteor, camera

i got a very strange behavior when i tried to load image from cdvfile://

**case 1:** 
i tried to load image with cordova `camera.getPicture` with options:

```
{
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI, 
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, 
  correctOrientation: true
}
```

so in this case, with `correctOrientation: true`, cordova made a copy of the original file and stored it in the app cache folder and in the callback i got the cache file path. Then i converted it into cdvfile, it worked perfectly.

**case 2:**
in case 1, i'm unhappy, because i want the original file path, so i can save it and reload it when i want. 
so i changed a bit the code:
the fastest way is removing the option `correctOrientation: true` so i get the originale file path, then with `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL`(same method in case 1), i get the cdvfile, i set it to `image.src` and bam:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

**so working perfectly with cached file:**

file uri: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{app_id}/cache/IMG_20170119_091504.jpg?1484813705413`

converted file url: `cdvfile://localhost/cache-external/IMG_20170119_091504.jpg`

**not working with original file:**

file uri: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A91315`

converted into cdvfile: `cdvfile://localhost/content/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A91316:1`

i'm really confused... any ideas to solve this error?

im using:

- angular@1.6.1
- meteor@1.4.2.3
- bundled cordova-android@5.2.2
- cordova-plugin-camera@2.2.0
- cordova-plugin-file@4.2.0
- nexus7@6.0.1

Comment: why do you need a cdvfile?

Comment: @BalaAbhinav i need the file path, so the app can reload the image next time i open it, or when i load a new project. i'm dont want to use data_url, its heavy to handle

Comment: Check this out. It addresses all the issues that you have posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph

Comment: yeah, the concept is same, but my problem is that i cannot load the image from `cdvfile://` scheme when the image is locate in `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document` ... it might be the uri decoding issue like in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638932/unable-to-load-image-when-selected-from-the-gallery-on-android-4-4-kitkat-usin)

Comment: well, i changed the approach to [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph) you have suggested, it's the best way